# What does grep line buffering do?

Tags: grep

Here's my command that I'm using in a script to `grep` real-time data. It doesn't seem to pull real-time data correctly as it just misses some lines.

```
tail -f <file> | fgrep "string" | sed 's/stuff//g' >> output.txt
```

What would the following command do? What is "line buffering"?

```
tail -f <file> | fgrep --line-buffered "string" | sed 's/stuff//g' >> output.txt
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

When using non-interactively, most standard commands, include `grep`, buffer the output, meaning it does not write data immediately to `stdout`. It collects large amount of data (depend on OS, in Linux, often 4096 bytes) before writing.

In your command, `grep`'s output is piped to `stdin` of `sed` command, so `grep` buffer its output.

So, `--line-buffered` option causing `grep` using line buffer, meaning writing output each time it saw a newline, instead of waiting to reach 4096 bytes by default. But in this case, you don't need `grep` at all, just use `tail` + `sed`:

```
tail -f <file> | sed '/string/s/stuff//g' >> output.txt
```

With command that does not have option to modify buffer, you can use [GNU coreutils stdbuf](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#stdbuf-invocation)

```
tail -f <file> | stdbuf -oL fgrep "string" | sed 's/stuff//g' >> output.txt
```

to turn on line buffering or using `-o0` to disable buffer.

**Note**

- [stdio buffering](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/)