# grep and pipe combination to filter standat input

Tags: bash, grep, pipe

Why this is working

```
gdbus monitor -y -d org.freedesktop.login1 | grep org
```

Filtering output lines containing "org"

This is working

```
gdbus monitor -y -d org.freedesktop.login1 | (while read LINE ; do echo "$(date) $LINE" ; done)
```

Printing date before line output

But this is not working.

```
gdbus monitor -y -d org.freedesktop.login1 | grep org | (while read LINE ; do echo "$(date) $LINE" ; done)
```

The intention here is to print out date before line output only for lines containing "org"

Comment: Try `grep --line-buffered` - see for example [What does grep line buffering do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/562344/what-does-grep-line-buffering-do) and [Read logs real time with bash](https://askubuntu.com/a/1395229/178692)

Comment: Or kill the gdbus process and let the buffers flush: kill -s INT `pidof gdbus`

Comment: --line-buffered helps, thanks